# redirect back to register page then add flash message upon registering using the make:auth() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i have this laravel app. Im using the `make:auth()` for my login and registration system. By default the registration will automatically goes to /home page. Now, i want to redirect my register page to itself then add a flash message to it. Not automatically login. I also added the `Session flash` message code to it. How will i able to achieve this? this is my code below. Can someone help me figured this thing out? 
Any help is muchly appreciated.TIA

`app\http\controllers\auth\RegisterController.php` :

```
 use RegistersUsers;



 /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'middleName'=> 'required|string|max:255',
            'lastName'=> 'required|string|max:255',
            'address'=> 'required|string|max:255',
            'contactNumber'=> 'required|string|max:255',
            'username'=> 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $membersNumber = time() . rand(10*45, 100*98);
        Session::flash('success', 'You are successfully registered! Serapio.ph will review your submitted documents and will text you if you can login.');
        return User::create([
            'members_number'=>$membersNumber,
            'first_name' => $data['firstName'],
            'middle_name'=>$data['middleName'],
            'last_name'=>$data['lastName'],
            'address'=>$data['address'],
            'contact_number'=>$data['contactNumber'],
            'username'=>$data['username'],
            'reference_person'=>$data['referencePerson'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

    }
```

`register.blade.php` :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Register | Serapio.ph')
@section('content')
<!-- BREADCRUMBS -->
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="page-title pull-left">Register</h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Register</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END BREADCRUMBS -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-horizontal">
            <!-- REGISTRATION FORM -->
            <br>
            <h2 class="section-heading">Member's Sign Up Info</h2>
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                @if (session('success'))
                   <p class="alert alert-success">{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
                @endif

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="{{ old('firstName') }}" placeholder="First Name" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middleName" name="middleName" value="{{ old('middleName') }}" placeholder="Middle Name" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="{{ old('lastName') }}" placeholder="Last Name" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" placeholder="Address" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" name="contactNumber" value="{{ old('contactNumber') }}" placeholder="Contact Number" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-horizontal" style='margin-top:95px;'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="referencePerson" name="referencePerson" value="" placeholder="Reference Person (Optional)" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" placeholder="Username" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="email" class="control-label sr-only">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="password" class="control-label sr-only">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password2" class="control-label sr-only">Repeat Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required placeholder="Repeat Password">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label style="color:red;">Note* Upload Seaman's Book/Students ID<br><i>Please upload file using PDF or JPG</i></label>
                        <input type="file" name="pdf"  />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" /> <a href="">Terms and Condition</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Create Account</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <!--<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>-->
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Do login but not login. I can't get it :(

Comment: by default the registration will automatically login. i dont want after registration that will automatically goes to /home page

Comment: Then, you want to redirect nack to `/register` right?

Comment: yes correct .....

Comment: Thanks anyways. I already solve it :)